# How to embed my gmail account in my webpage in HTML

Tags: html

I am using HTML and my task is to create a portfolio website, I need to embed my Gmail account in the webpage, I am trying it using an anchor tag

```
<a href="____">userid@gmail.com</a>
```

I did

```
<a href="userid@gmail.com">userid@gmail.com</a>
```

This fails !!

I need help, in that href section, I need a supporting link that, when clicked will redirect a user directly to their compose box with my mail id in the To: section

Comment: See [`mailto` links](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/)

Comment: thanks for your help 
but mailto: opens systems Mail app

i needed it to redirect me on another tab 

please take a look at the answer i posted

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently though some accident, I stumbled upon the answer, on google classroom, where my professor shared her mail id, which when clicked redirected me on my mail account with Compose open and her mail id entered in the To: section

alright!, I don't know the jargon for it, I think it's Google's Mail API, correct me if I'm wrong.

However, the solution for that is this link:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?view=cm&fs=1&to=userid@gmail.com&tf=1
```

I only had to put this link in my HTML in the href= section and boom ! it worked

```
    <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?view=cm&fs=1&to=userid@gmail.com&tf=1
">userid@gmail.com</a>
```

the

> userid@gmail.com

is deliberately put as such , you can enter yours as it is !